# Interpret variables from read in string with shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, read

I have a text file which is usually filled with multiple lines which I want to "print" with a while loop. The text inside this file contains variables - my problem is, that these variables are not interpreted unlike a similar test-string containing variables stored inside the script. Is it possible to also interpret those variables from my external file or do I have to parse them beforehands etc.? What is the difference between `$LINE_INSIDE` and `$LINE_OUTSIDE`?
I tried some suggestions from other questions like `${!varialbe_name}` and different constructs with quote signs but with no luck so far.

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    # color.sh
    BLUE='\033[1;34m'
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color

    LINE_INSIDE="${BLUE}Blue Text${NC}"
    echo -e ${LINE_INSIDE}

    while read LINE_OUTSIDE; do
            echo -e ${LINE_OUTSIDE}
    done < text_file
```

Output:

[image: Output of the script]

Additional Information: I (indeed) also have shell-commands in my input-text-file which should not by executed. Only the variables should be expaned.

Comment: `eval "echo -e ${LINE_OUTSIDE}"`

Comment: A better comparison would be `LINE_INSIDE='${BLUE}Blue Text${NC}'` (single quotes).

Comment: Please provide a sample set of lines of input data, illustrating variables that must be expanded and commands that must not.

Comment: First of all: My primary problem is solved with @Stéphane's answer.
Secondly fyi: The input are shell-commands for look-up purposes (a cheat-list) with a caption/description, e.g.:
`Mit Grep gefilterten Output an weiteren Befehl weiterleiten
ls ${BLUE}/pfad${NC} | grep -e '${GREEN}Regular Expression${NC}' | xargs -I{} sudo mv {} ${BLUE}/pfad${NC}

Löschen mit Fortschrittsanzeige
sudo rm -rv ${BLUE}/pfad${NC} | pv -l -s $(sudo find ${BLUE}/pfad${NC} | pv -l | wc -l) > /dev/null`
I should have mentioned it at the first place, so maybe I open a followup question regarding that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to write it as:

```bsh
BLUE=$'\033[1;34m'
NC=$'\033[0m' # No Color

eval "cat << EOF
$(<text_file)
EOF
"
```

than using a `while read` loop ([that's not the right syntax for reading lines btw](/q/209123)).

Of course that means that code in there would be interpreted. A `$(reboot)` in there for instance would cause a reboot, but that's more or less what you're asking for.

That also assumes the `text_file` doesn't contain an `EOF` line.

Another approach that would **only** do variable (environment variable) substitution (and not command substitution for instance) would be to use GNU `gettext`'s `envsubst`:

```
BLUE=$'\033[1;34m'
NC=$'\033[0m' # No Color
export BLUE NC
envsubst < text_file
```

Or so that only those two variables are expanded:

```
BLUE=$'\033[1;34m'
NC=$'\033[0m' # No Color
export BLUE NC
envsubst '$BLUE$NC' < text_file
```

Comment: I indeed have shell-commands in my text file, which should not be executed. I added this information to my original question.
So the second part of your answer (export + envsub) (`while IFS= read LINE_OUTSIDE; do; echo -e ${LINE_OUTSIDE} | envsubst; done < text_file`) is what perfectly solves my problem.

Comment: @n-tchen that code of yours has a lot of problems, which could be eliminated by reducing it to simply `envsubst <text_file`. Notice however that `envsubst` is an obscure, non-standard command -- even `perl -pe 's/\$\{(\w+)\}/$ENV{$1}/g'` would be **much** more portable -- and could be easily modified to leave alone the variables it doesn't know about: `perl -pe 's|\$\{(\w+)\}|$ENV{$1}//$&|ge'`.

Comment: @mosvy I guess I broke the problem too much down. In my actual script I do a couple of steps more (inside the loop) of "formatting" the text-file, so `envsubst <text_file` isn't an option for me!? Or can I combine this with a loop in an other way like I did? Otherwise it would be a completely new question with "How do I code this more elegante". The script is only for me, so portability isn't important, but I keep your words in mind for other purposes.

Comment: That's not about elegance. You're omitting the `-r` option of read and fail to properly quote your variables (which makes the `IFS=` quite pointless -- unless IFS was *really* changed in your script, its *only* purpose is to preserve the *trailing* spaces from the line, that were already lost in the unquoted `${...}`). And the `envsubst` is one extra fork + exec per line. But as you said, if the script is just for you, I guess that using `bash` is a form of penitence or masochism, so completely different standards may apply ;-)

Comment: Okay, I understand. The missing `-r` was just a typo (even though it's, in my case, also working without), but the quotes seems to be a point to think about. Next time my brain is capable enough I will go through your criticism, also regarding using bash.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of `bash` (since version 4.4 or so) there's yet another tricky way to indirectly expand variables in strings, without having to go full `eval`: the `@P` parameter transformation (= expand as in [prompts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html), including but not limited to variable substitutions).

```
$ cat file.txt
${BLUE}hello blue${NORM}

$ BLUE=$'\e[34m'
$ NORM=$'\e[m'
$ while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "${line@P}"; done < file.txt
hello blue
```

Comment: In case anyone is in doubt, it is not any less dangerous than using `eval`. If `$(reboot)` is in `file.txt`, that would still reboot.